# Charles Stearns (1753-1832) Photograph

Tags: identification-request

There is a photo of Charles Stearns which appears in the article [Theatre for Young Audiences: A Timeline](https://www.sutori.com/story/theatre-for-young-audiences-a-timeline--8hWoa1VzoyAc1wAiN6TKfHrF).

I don’t know if this a true photo of Charles Stearns.

Does anyone know where to find a photograph of Charles Stearns (1753-1826), of Lincoln Liberal School, MA?

Comment: If he died in 1832, there can't be any photographs of him — the oldest surviving [photograph of a person is from 1838](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boulevard_du_Temple_(photograph)).

Comment: There were  probably no photographs of your Stearns.  The first widely used form of photography didn't appear until 1839.  The illustration on the page you cite is probably one of somebody else, perhaps also called Charles Stearns.

Answer (score 4):

You photograph seems to be of [George Luther Stearns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Luther_Stearns) (1809-1867).  The [original](https://exhibits.tufts.edu/spotlight/john-brown-tufts/catalog/9-618) seems to be in the West Virginia State Archives.

As mentioned in comments by Gareth Rees and myself, your Charles Stearns died  (in 1826 according to his [grave stone](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/38082853/charles-stearns)) before commercial photography and portrait photographs existed.

Comment: Perfect. Got it. Thank You..

Comment: If this answer satisfactorily answered your question, please click the checkmark under to voting arrows to accept it. This will mark the question as solved.